# Minimum value of $[a,b]$ = $[a,2a]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maxima-minima, number-systems, least-common-multiple

Given that $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ are positive integers such that $a<b<c<d<e$. Find the maximum value of $$\frac1{[a,b]} +\frac1{[b,c]} +\frac1{[c,d]} + \frac1{[d,e]},$$ where $[x,y]$ denotes the LCM of $x$ and $y$

Taking $b = 2a$
Hence,  $$\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(2,4)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(4,8)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(8,16)}=\frac{15}{16}$$
***So can anyone come up with valid proof that minimum value of $[a,b]$ = $[a,2a]$***

Comment: such that a?... and then?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You've been on this site long enough that you should know that there are ways to mess with the formatting, including in this case a `<` without math mode. If you had just bothered to press the "edit" button, you would've seen the full question was there. That doesn't excuse someone who posts a question without looking at the preview, but you could've edited it yourself as well.

Comment: And to @TemidireAdesiji, what have you tried?

Comment: @Author Have tried applying LCM(x,y)=ab/gcd(a,b). But I didn't know what next or how to go about it.

Comment: Note that $a$ divides $[a,b]$. If you want to minimize $[a,b]$ therefore, you can simply choose $b = 2a$. Can you see how this helps?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг so the solution would be $$\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(2,4)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(4,8)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(8,16)}=\frac{15}{16}$$

Comment: @Raffaele So I  would think. Can we come up with a proof of this?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please Prove $[a,b]$ = $[a,2a]$ in the Solutions

Comment: @Raffaele please prove why $[a,b]$ = $[a,2a]$

Comment: @TemidireAdesiji $2a$ is a multiple of $a$ and of itself and is the minimum, the least. Like $\text{lcm}(5,10)=10$...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minimize $[a,b]$ therefore, you can simply choose $b = 2a$ ,Note : b = a would have been the minimum but since $b>a$ and $b \neq a$  but so we have to look for the next integer multiple of which 2 is so $b = 2a$, since $b>a$ and $b \neq a$

Hence,  $$\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(2,4)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(4,8)}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(8,16)}=\frac{15}{16}$$

Thanks to @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг and Raffaele

Comment: yet you didn't explain why is that the max

Comment: @nedgrekerzberg Hope the edited solution answer your question, and u can always test it with series of values.

Comment: Hey! You have to thank me too :)